# Equality checking in F#

Tags: f#, constraints

I'm trying to write a function where I have a helper function, 'a -> bool. My problem is, when I'm trying to use the return value from this helper function, I get the error (because it is a function?)

> The type `'a -> bool' does not support the 'equality' constraint`,

Is there a way to get it to pre-evaluate the function so that I can use the return value?

Example:

```
let primelist n =
    let rec prim n = function
        | []                   -> true
        | x::xs when n % x = 0 -> false
        | x::xs                -> prim n xs

    let rec help n list = function
        | n when (prim n = true) -> List.rev (n::list)
        | n                      -> List.rev list
        | i when (prim i = true) -> help n (i::list) (i+1)
        | i                      -> help n list (i+1)
    help [2] n
```

Comment: Just found the fault my self ^^

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
let primelist n =
    let rec prim n = function
        | []                   -> true
        | x::xs when n % x = 0 -> false
        | x::xs                -> prim n xs

    let rec help n list arg =
        let prime n = prim n list
        match arg with
        | n when (prime n = true) -> List.rev (n::list)
        | n                       -> List.rev list
        | i when (prime i = true) -> help n (i::list) (i+1)
        | i                       -> help n list (i+1)
    help [2] n
```

Here I have used currying to create a new function.

Comment: Aren't `| n when (prime n = true)` and `| i when (prime i = true)` duplicate cases? `| n` and `| i`?

Comment: definitely looks the case, but I thought just fix one thing at a time